# thinkpad_acpi.h missing from /usr/include/linux

Tags: 13.10, kernel

I have a strange issue with Saucy, that cannot figure out. I usually patch the kernel with a well-known patch for Lenovo Mic Mute led. However since latest kernel updates, I've lost the header file `/usr/include/linux/thinkpad_acpi.h` which is needed for the patch to compile.
As I see in kernel packages - the file should exist in linux-kernel-headers, but when I try to install it, I get the message:

```
Note, selecting 'linux-libc-dev' instead of 'linux-kernel-headers'
```

And in linux-libc-dev the file is missing. Can someone explain how and when linux-libc-dev replaced linux-kernel-headers, and why the header file `thinkpad_acpi.h` is missing there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, for some reason the .h file re-appeared in newer kernel updates:

```
/usr/src/linux-headers-3.11.0-17/include/linux/thinkpad_acpi.h
```

The problem with missing header file was with 3.11.0-13 or 15, I can't remember exactly. Seems that the issue was later fixed.